# Visual Studio build hangs on Roslyn csc.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, dll

We are having an issue where the VS compiler gets stuck indefinitely and doesn't return an error when we cancel. There were some warnings about package versions conflicting like System.Web.Http, but after putting bindingRedirect's for those packages the warnings have gone away but the hanging problem remains. The issue is reproducible on different workstations, so I don't believe a reinstall of VS will help. The build output it gets stuck on is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /checked+ /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /errorreport:send /warn:4 /define:DEBUG /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:\\nfiv-web-01d\www\Apps\vendor\bin\ACE.dll /reference:\\nfiv-web-01d\www\Apps\vendor\bin\Antlr3.Runtime.dll... (rest of arguments omitted)`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that compiling never finishes, or that CSC is always running in TaskManager?

Comment: The compiling never finishes, and when it is manually cancelled, CSC remains running in task manager. So I have to kill the process and try again, but with the same result.

Comment: Are you compiling on a local machine, or are you accessing is via Citrix or RDC or some other remote desktop?

Comment: Normally the source lives on a remote machine and we compile using a local install of VS. We have tried copying the source to a local workspace and compiling it there, and we have the same issue.

Comment: @triangore please let me know if you solved this issue. im facing the same issue